# time.h | time(0) and localtime(time_t) combinations returns previous time if time zone changed in between

Tags: c++, c, crt, time.h

Running the below code as per steps, time(0) and localtime() combinations returns different time.

**Versions used - C v60 (visual studio 15)**

```
int main()
{
    time_t t = time(0);      // Line 1
    tm *t2 = localtime(&t);  // Line 2
    //codes                  // Line 3
    time_t t1 = time(0);     // Line 4
    tm *t4 = localtime(&t1); // Line 5
    return 0;
}
```

**Steps:**

- Line 1 - Current time zone UTC+00 - 11.40 am (Before time zone change)
- Line 2 - Returns UTC +00 - 11.40 am (As Expected)
- Line 3 - Some other codes. And assume time zone is changed to UTC-01 by some external events. (Time zone Change)
- Line 4 - As time zone is changed, expected time is UTC-01 - 10.40am.
- Line 5 - Returns UTC +00 - 11.40 am (Not as expected)

> functions _tstrtime() /_strtime() are returning UTC-01 - 10.40 am at
> Line 4/5 (expected)

*Additionally, I've tried using std::time() and std::localtime() from c++, getting the same behaviour*

**Question : How to get the correct time even when the system's time zone is getting changed in between ?**

Comment: So what's your question? And where exactly is the supposedly working code example?

Comment: Updated the question. The code I've posted is working example for replicating the issue

Comment: What time is the "correct" time?

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's very Zen

Comment: Thank you @systemcpro, I think, but to be clear, the question is a serious one.  The OP had not clearly characterized the time they want to obtain.

Comment: Guys, I've updated the question again. Please check

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-localtime32-localtime64?view=msvc-160 <- do you have the environment variable TZ set by any chance? if yes, you should unset it I guess, otherwise the program will use its value instead of the current setting

Comment: Feature, not a bug, the first use of any CRT function that requires local time sets the "TZ" environment variable.  To be used again in the future.  It isn't that clear to me whether resetting the variable will work, the code is convoluted, but worth a try.

Comment: Dop you use C or C++?

Comment: @HansPassant I tried using _tzset() but no luck. can you please suggest how do we reset it.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I've tried using std::time(nullptr) from <ctime> and time(NULL) from <time.h> both gives the same behavior

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv-s-wputenv-s?view=msvc-160

Comment: @Pravinkumar Is your question about C or C++? This are 2 different language, do not ask the same question for 2 different languages at the same time except you want to know the difference, how to write code that works in both or need to interact between them.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Ok, Issue is in C when using <time.h> -> time(NULL) and localtime.

Comment: Then why do you use the C++ tag? And why do you use a C++ compiler? Decide for one language, make the question for that language only and when you have a similar problem in any other language too, make a new question.

Comment: `//put a break point and change the time zone in your system;` needs to be replaced with code - not external operations messing with the data.  It is like saying `a = 42; printf("%d\n", a); /* break point, change a=7 */ printf("%d\n", a);` and complaining that code renders the same output.

Comment: An alternative would be to report the local time with `strftime()` and `"%Z"`  (locale’s time zone name or abbreviation - if available).  I'd expect the 2nd time to report  the correct time, in the former timezone and the observer would know its the former timezone rather than the unadorned "10.40" or "11.40".  This is why it is valuable to report time with its timezone.  See [iso 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Comparing C and C++ is not like comparing Javascript and FORTRAN. I believe this issue can be replicated both in C and C++ libraries. Ok, on your way, can you please try to give me a solution using either of this language.

Comment: @Pravinkumar No, C and C++ are different languages. `std::time` only exist in C++. I and many other people are not willing to help people that don't want to take the effort of asking correctly.

Comment: @Pravinkumar No reason to get upset. You ask other for help so take the effort and do your part. If don't want to put in this effort, don't expect other people to take the effort to help you (for free). You problem depends not only on language and system, it also depends on how you start your program. On my system the time changes when i call the executable one way but it does not when i call it the other way.

Comment: read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-localtime32-localtime64?view=msvc-160 , https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/tzset?view=msvc-160 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-timezone?view=msvc-160